# transaction_details.gross_amount is not a number, How to change to input value even if the API request it as number?

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up a custom payment gateway using an API, The API request the transaction_details.gross_amount as a number not minimum than 10000 like this:

```
 transaction_details: {
        gross_amount: 100000,
           }
```

What I want is that this gross_amount get some value as the user input  field:

I try to like this but couldn't help:

```
var trying = document.getElementById('give-amount').value;
    var gross_amount = new String("");
    var requestBody = 
    {
      transaction_details: {
        gross_amount: trying,

      }
    }
```

Its good I get some user input amount in the 'give-amount' field but still giving me the error transaction_details.gross_amount is not a number.

The question is how to change the gross_amount to get the user input value without getting the error that is not a number.

Comment: `var gross_amount = new String("");` what is this? hint: irrelevant and not used ...

Comment: simplest fix: `var trying = +document.getElementById('give-amount').value;` though, you may want to have some error checking in case some idiot put's in something that isn't a number ... you could `var trying = +document.getElementById('give-amount').value || 0;` which will mean trying will be a number, guaranteed ... of course, it could be negative too ... so, again, some validation will be required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the integer using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and then further pass it down to the body.
Also, you don't need to declare a new string.

To add, when doing parseInt over a string (or some other data type), it might return `NaN` i.e. Not a Number - so you wouldn't want to send that to the server too.
For that, you can add a safe check that if parseInt fails, then send 0 or any other value that you'd like.

```
var trying = parseInt(document.getElementById('give-amount').value) || 0,
  requestBody = {
    transaction_details: {
      gross_amount: trying
    }
  };
```

If you're interested in having decimal values,
then you can use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of parseInt.

Comment: I'm just yanking your chain :p I'll remove my comments since he's accepted this :p but it does highlight (to the OP) that care should be taken when asking a question :p

Comment: Thanks so much, Works perfectly! I was thinking of parseInt but I couldn't write it how before, sorry I'm newbie and thanks again.